# Google maps - Display a map and a marker by retrieving latitude and longitube with php

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a database of points in latitude and longitude format (ex. 32.3185414, -86.954298) and I want to display a map of each point on its own webpage.

I would like to display a marker of that point on the map with a tooltip (if possible) displaying custom text. I use php. Is it possible?

Comment: A tooltip is an [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows). More info [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3) about querying a database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use Google map javascrip Api for showing your lat long points on webpage.

See this link

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

and for tooltip you can use

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: point,
    title:"Hello World!"
});
```

## Codelord